# Flutter Background messages internationalization

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, internationalization

In my flutter app, i want to **translate** some text in the push notification body.

For foreground notifications. there is no problem.

For backgroud notifiactions i use :

```
void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

And `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` must be a top-level function.

So, how can i use my famous  `AppLocalizations.of(context).cancel,` since I don't have a context here ?

Comment: I had similar problem and found answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67296138/2896582

Answer (score 2):

Since `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` is a top-level function- you can pass `context` as an optional parameter. So that you can access the context.

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message,
    {BuildContext? context}){
   
       //Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MyApp create variable static
Exp:

```
static BuildContext? mContext;
```

in build function of MyApp

```
mContext = context;
```